# Problem with the ZEOSDBO component on DELPHI

Tags: delphi, kylix

I have a problem with DELPHI with the ZEOSDBO Component when
i try to use the CLX library by adding example a ZPgSqlDatabase and a DBEdit the following msg appears when i try to execute.

```
[Error] WARNING. Duplicate resource(s):
[Error] Type 10 (RCDATA), ID TLOGINDIALOG:
[Error] File c:/program files/Borland/delphi6/Lib/QDBLogDlg.xfm resource
kept; file c:/program files/Borland/delphi6/Lib/DBLOGDLG.dfm resource
discarded.
```

I'm developing a system in Delphi and Kylix
Could someone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict between CLX and VCL (they both define a `TLoginDialog` class). There is a (Portuguese) page [here](https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/a-todos-que-usam-o-componente-zeos-solucao-para-o-problema/138569) that describes the issue. It seems Zeos uses some VCL units, hence the conflict.

You can try replacing references to `DBLogDlg` with references to `QDBLogDlg` in Zeos source.